# UWSGI crash when started as service and POST big file: ConnectionError

Tags: python, debian, uwsgi

I'm facing an inexplicable problem with uwsgi: Crashs irregular happens when upload a big file size. Scenario:

**Context**

For a simple wsgi application, here a python Flask application in */home/bastien/Projects/test_upload/wsgi.py*:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def hello_world():
    f = request.files['file'].read()
    return 'Hello, World! {}'.format(len(f))

application = app
```

**No crash when**:

Use this configuration uwsgi file, */etc/uwsgi/apps-available/test_upload.ini*:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = python3
chdir = /home/bastien/Projects/test_upload/tracim
home = /home/bastien/Projects/test_upload/venv3.4
module = wsgi
callable = application
enable-threads = true
env = PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp
limit-post = 0
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

Run uwsgi with:

```
uwsgi -i /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/test_upload.ini --http-socket :6543
```

And send file (~262Mo) with `/httpie`:

```
http -h -f POST :6543 'file@/home/bastien/Téléchargements/pycharm-professional-2017.2.3.tar.gz'
```

HTTP request can be repeated, no crash.

**Crash when**:

Use this configuration uwsgi file, */etc/uwsgi/apps-available/test_upload.ini* with symbolic link into */etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled*:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = python3
chdir = /home/bastien/Projects/test_upload/tracim
home = /home/bastien/Projects/test_upload/venv3.4
module = wsgi
callable = application
http-socket = :4321
enable-threads = true
env = PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp
limit-post = 0
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

*Note*: Only difference is `http-socket = :4321`

Run uwsgi with `service uwsgi start` (on debian 8.9) and send file with:

```
http -h -f POST :4321 'file@/home/bastien/Téléchargements/pycharm-professional-2017.2.3.tar.gz'
```

This request will work one time, sometimes two times:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 5188
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Pragma: no-cache
```

But finally crash with:

> http: error: ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",)) while doing POST request to URL: http://localhost:4321/

*Note*: Any wsgi application can be used for reproduce

*Note*: No log is produced by uwsgi or application about this "error"

**Summary**:

The error is not conistent and only difference is uwsgi usage as service with:

- Debian 8.9
- uwsgi `2.0.7-1+deb8u1` apt installed

**Question**

How can produce this difefrence ? Where can i search to know **how** is started uwsgi by `service` command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved when use Debian 9 with uwsgi in apt version `2.0.14+20161117-3`.